# python парсер контента с сайта

Tags: python, парсер

кто знает почему парсер на python может вылетать без ошибок?
Все модули установил(requests, beautifulsoup4)

Я пытался ещё и копировать чужой код парсера с этого сайта - но та же проблема

Версия python - 3.8.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.tut.by/kurs/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
v_name = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"b-course"})
for x in v_name:
    course = x.find("p")
    print(course.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

выполнил ваш код - `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined`, ок `import requests`:

> 2.4080
>   2.4140
>   2.4090
>   2.6550
>   2.6600
>   2.6425
>   3.3960
>   3.4100
>   3.3935 7 ...

Comment: простите что не скопировал полностью, у меня есть requests в коде. Только вылет без ошибок чтоб загуглить в чем может быть проблема

Comment: код у вас рабочий. вы запускаете его из консоли? или может Pycharm, MS VS?